# javascript Error - for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I wrote a this simple code in js.

```
    var n=10;
    for (i=1;i=n;i++){
    console.log('avinsyh');
     }
```

But the loop executes greater than 2000 and crashing the browser.Why this is happening so?

**Note:** If I  Execute this:

```
 var n=10;
    for (i=1;i<n;i++){
    console.log('avinsyh');
     }
```

Then the javascritpt outputs the correct results

Comment: `for (START, LIMIT, INCREMENT)` you have `for (START, START, INCREMENT)`

Comment: A single equals sign (=) is assignment operator, you will need to use a double equals sign (==) which is the comparison operator, in the second part of the for loop

Comment: @Valeklosse Even if put (i == n ) the code is not executing also no error

Comment: @Avinash the code probably is executing, but because i (1) is not equal to n (10), it wont enter the loop, in effect the loop will only ever excute once in this manner. If you want it to run until i(1) == n(10), then best to use != or <=

Answer (score 3):

It's the assignment in the comparison part of the [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), which makes an infinite loop. `i` becomes always `n` and evaluates to `true`.

```
for (i = 1; i = n; i++){
//          ^^^^^
```

```js
var n = 10,
    i;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    document.write('i: ' + i + '<br>');
}
```

Comment: `for (i=1; i < n; i++){` opposite.

Answer (score 2):

in your first  for loop , `i=n` will set `i` equal to the value of `n` and thus return a truthy value(as `n` is not 0) and you get a infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

In your [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement) you are assinging the value `i = n` which is always true and hence results in infinite loop.

> The condition expression is evaluated. If the value of condition is
>   true, the loop statements execute. If the value of condition is false,
>   the for loop terminates. If the condition expression is omitted
>   entirely, the condition is assumed to be true.

In your second case you are comparing the value of `i` on each iteration and hence you are getting the expected result.

The basic syntax of for loop is:

```
for ([initialExpression]; [condition]; [incrementExpression])  
 statement
```

So in your first case you are not providing the `[condition]` rather it is an assignment.